# Youtube api filtered search for latest videos added today

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

what should be added to this youtube api search query to get the latest video songs that are added in Youtube today.      `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?v=2&alt=jsonc&q=latest%20video%20songs&max-results=50"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Data API v3. Just with [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) call with [publishedAfter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedAfter) filter.

E.g.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&publishedAfter=2013-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```